# How to improve my accordian control collapse(close) code?

Tags: jquery

I have use accordion control in my asp.net page, i have used js in toggle-close function for co laps accordion control.
but i have pass div header id, please suggest how to improve the code.

```
    function ToggleClose(divHeaderId) {

    MainDivClickCount = 1;
    if (divHeaderId == '#divBasicDetails') {

        //divPersonelDetails
        $('#divPersonelDetails img').attr({ src: '../../Images/plus-icon.png' });
        $('#divPersonelDetails').removeClass("tabMinus");
        $('#divPersonelDetails').addClass("tabPlus");
        $('#divPersonelDetails').find('table').find('tr').find('td').removeClass("tabOpen");
        $('#divPersonelDetails').find('table').find('tr').find('td').addClass("tabClose");
        $('#divOtherDetails img').attr({ src: '../../Images/plus-icon.png' });
        $('#divOtherDetails').removeClass("tabMinus");
        $('#divOtherDetails').addClass("tabPlus");
        $('#divOtherDetails').find('table').find('tr').find('td').removeClass("tabOpen");
        $('#divOtherDetails').find('table').find('tr').find('td').addClass("tabClose");

    }
    else if (divHeaderId == '#divPersonelDetails') {
        $('#divBasicDetails img').attr({ src: '../../Images/plus-icon.png' });
        $('#divBasicDetails').removeClass("tabMinus");
        $('#divBasicDetails').addClass("tabPlus");
        $('#divBasicDetails').find('table').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').removeClass("tabOpen");
        $('#divBasicDetails').find('table').find('tbody').find('tr').find('td').addClass("tabClose");

        $('#divOtherDetails img').attr({ src: '../../Images/plus-icon.png' });
        $('#divOtherDetails').removeClass("tabMinus");
        $('#divOtherDetails').addClass("tabPlus");
        $('#divOtherDetails').find('table').find('tr').find('td').removeClass("tabOpen");
        $('#divOtherDetails').find('table').find('tr').find('td').addClass("tabClose");

 }
}
```

Comment: Use classes instead of unique ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can massively reduce this code by placing the selector of the `divBasicDetails` and `divPersonelDetails` into a variable which is set by the provided `divHeaderId`. You can also then join the selected div with `divOtherDetails` as you're performing the same logic on both elements, and you can use `toggleClass` in place of multiple `addClass`/`removeClass` calls. Try this:

```
function ToggleClose(divHeaderId) {
    MainDivClickCount = 1; // this can possibly be removed, as you don't appear to use it

    var idSelector = divHeaderId == '#divBasicDetails' ? '#divPersonelDetails' : '#divBasicDetails';
    var $divs = $(idSelector).add('#divOtherDetails');

    $divs.toggleClass('tabMinus tabPlus');
    $divs.find('img').attr('src', '../../Images/plus-icon.png');
    $divs.find('table tr td').toggleClass('tabOpen tabClose');
}
```